# C# Entity Framework Core .Include() issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm having a problem with the entity framework's "Include()" function

Framework used: .NET Core 3.1 with Entity Framework Core 3.1.5

These are my entities

```
public class EntityA
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int EntityBId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityBId")]
    public EntityB EntityB { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

so I launch this query:

```
public ICollection<EntityA> GetAll(string contextName)
{
    DbContext context = GetContext(contextName);

    ICollection<EntityA> collection = context.EntityAs
        .Include(j => j.EntityB)
        .Where(x => x.IsConfirmed)
        .ToList();

    return collection;
}

private DbContext GetContext(string contextName)
{
    string contextDbConnectionString = _secretsRepository.GetDbConnectionString(contextName);

    DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(contextDbConnectionString);

    return new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
}
```

the result of the query is as follows:

```
{
    Id: 5
    IsConfirmed: true
    EntityB: null
    EntityBId: 72
}
```

what I don't understand is why the "Include(j => j.EntityB)" does not return the EntityB field correctly valued

Comment: Try marking `EntityB` as `virtual`, so `public virtual EntitiyB EntityB {get; set}`

Comment: Please check the generated SQL to start with. Does it include the EntityB?

Comment: @MindSwipe I tried as you said but nothing has changed

Comment: @TomTom I had already looked at it but the result of the generated query is this: `SELECT [p].[Id],  [p].[IsConfirmed], [p].[EntityBId]
FROM [EntityAs] AS [p]
HERE [p].[IsConfirmed] = CAST(1 AS bit)`

Comment: Ok, so EfCore is not generating the SQL.Your DbContext is NOT registering the metadata properly, so relationships are never parsed. Look up how to configure the DbContext properly.

Comment: @TomTom I checked my configuration, and being code first the relations on the db are correct, but ef don't fill the navigation properties

Comment: try the where clause first and then call include or just remove the where clause complete to find if where clause is the culprit.Where(x => x.IsConfirmed).Include(j => j.EntityB)

Comment: @GertArnold The database i SQL Server on azure, the `Index` library is `Assembly EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, namespace:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`

Comment: Then you have EF core 3.1 and EF6 in one project. You shouldn't do that. Indexes can only be configured by fluent API in EF core.

Comment: Thanks I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to build a data model with the entities provided in question, I encountered a compilation error at Index attribute.

```
[Required]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public int EntityBId { get; set; }
```

Turns out entity framework 6 libraries used to have that attribute, but the question talks about entity framework core. So I just removed the Index attribute and moved it to OnModelCreating method to mimic similar behavior.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().HasIndex(u => u.EntityBId).IsUnique();
}
```

With that in place,I applied code first approach to generate the db and ran the program. Upon execution, ef core generated proper query:

```
SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[EntityBId], [e].[IsConfirmed], [e0].[Id], [e0].[Description], 
[e0].[Title]
FROM [EntityAs] AS [e]
INNER JOIN [EntityBs] AS [e0] ON [e].[EntityBId] = [e0].[Id]
WHERE [e].[IsConfirmed] = CAST(1 AS bit)
```

Hope it helps in resolving your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, my problem was due to the entity framework 6 library with entity framework core library